# How to add fieldset in Magento custom admin form when field select value changed

Tags: magento-1, javascript, forms, adminform, fieldsets

I have a select field like this in my costum magento admin form

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'category_id',
    'select',
    array(
        'id'    => 'lazadaCategory',
        'label'  => Mage::helper('test_sellercenter')->__('Category '),
        'name'   => 'status',
        'values' => Mage::helper('test_sellercenter/dropdown')->getLazadaCategories(),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
    )
);
```

and when the select value change i need to add another fields below this select field (not like toogle show/hide just add), for example like this field

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'listing_name',
    'text',
    array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('test_sellercenter')->__('Listing Name'),
        'name'  => 'listing_name',
        'required'  => true,
        'class' => 'required-entry',

    )
);
```

is there a way to do this in magento? for example like this [add field example](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use `field dependencies` feature of Magento, like here is the example

```
$status = $fieldSet->addField('status', 'select', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Status'),
    'name'      => 'status',
    'values'    => array(
        'Approved' => 'Approved',
        'Denied'   => 'Denied'
    )
));

$denyReason = $fieldSet->addField('denial_reason', 'textarea', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('module')->__('Denial Reason'),
    'name'      => 'denial_reason'
));
```

And add your dependencies

```
$this->setForm($form);
$this->setChild('form_after', $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
    ->addFieldMap($status->getHtmlId(), $status->getName())
    ->addFieldMap($denyReason->getHtmlId(), $denyReason->getName())                     
    ->addFieldDependence(
        $denyReason->getName(),
        $status->getName(),
        'Denied'
    )
);
```

`$denyReason` field only display If status is set to `Denied`. According to this you can define your `field dependencies.`

Comment: that's just like show/hide , what i want is like this [link](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery)

Comment: It was my bad ,, sorry :)

Comment: No problem :), i hope you can help me with this question :D

Answer (score 0):

use `setAfterElementHtml` function. Suppose, you want to show/hide the following field:

```
$fieldset->addField('field_to_hide', text, array(
    'label'  => $this->__('Test'),
));
```

Here is the dropdown/select field. It’s a yes/no field. Suppose, upon selecting ‘Show’, you will need to show the above mentioned field. And, upon selecting ‘Hide’, you will need to hide the above field.

Note the `onChange` parameter here. It’s calling `showHideField()` JS function.

```
$selectField = $fieldset->addField('select_field', 'select', array(
    'label' => 'Show/Hide Selection',
    'name' => 'select_field',           
    'values' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => 'Show',
        ),
        array(
            'value' => 0,
            'label' => 'Hide',
        ),
    ),
    'onChange'  => 'showHideField()',
));
```

The `setAfterElementHtml` is called which contains Javascript code to show/hide field

```
$selectField->setAfterElementHtml('
    <script>
    function showHideField() {                                              
        $("field_to_hide").toggle()
    }
    </script>
');
```

Comment: i dont want to show/hide field, i need to add more field when onchange function triggered